# Duplicate class build errors

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

Thanks in advance for any help
I have an app that stores most of it's data on firebase, however, for cost reasons, stores the videos to AWS s3 storage. Today I am getting these build errors.

1. Yes I have read the "Fix Dependency Resolution errors" suggestions
2. My question is how do I fix this

Here are the dependencies in my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    // Support for Java 8 features
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.1'

    // Firestore
    //implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'

    // FirebaseUI (for authentication)
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.1.0'

    // Other Firebase/Play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'

    // Support Libs
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    // Android architecture components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    // ExoPlayer
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.12.0'

    // Third-party libraries
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.0.2'

    // Amplify core dependency
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:1.16.13'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:1.16.13'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.16.13'

    // AWS
    implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.0')
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.404'
}
```

Here is **SOME** of the errors

```
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AbortedException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException$ErrorType found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceResponse found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.DefaultRequest found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.HttpMethod found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.Protocol found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.Request found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.1-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.1) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.0')
```

this one provide 2.22.1 version of aws java sdk to the request below

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
```

this one request the 2.22.1 version of s3 and core sdk from above

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.404'
```

this one provide all 1.11.404 version of aws java sdk, include s3 and core, so this is where the duplicate class happened.

See also [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html)

Comment: Thanks @ming-chen, still having issues, I've removed all references to sdk as recommended by **Jameson** below, the problem is setting permission to a file before uploading, and importing the necessary resources was causing the conflict, namely: **AmazonS3ClientBuilder** and **ProfileCredentialsProvider**, am looking into how to get around this.

Comment: @HemmaRoyD Sorry I can't help you with this, I'm not familiar with Amazon S3.

Comment: thank you for your help anyway, seems I have to use the underlying **AWSS3StoragePlugin**, to get around this problem as Amplify does not provide an "out of the box" solution, so am trawling through that to get a solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using two conflicting products:

**[AWS Amplify Android](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android)**

```
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:1.16.13'
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:1.16.13'
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.16.13'
```

And also the **[AWS Java SDK V1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java#aws-sdk-for-java-)**

```
implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.0')
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.404'
```

The AWS Mobile team does not support use of the V1 Java SDK on an Android device. I would start by removing these dependencies entirely.

Please follow this documentation to onboard Storage functionalities with Amplify Android:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/android

Source: I am an engineer on AWS' mobile team.

Comment: Thanks @jameson, the problem is setting permission to a file before uploading, and importing the necessary resources, this was causing the conflict, namely: **AmazonS3ClientBuilder** and **ProfileCredentialsProvider**